# IP aliasing to a bridge interface under systemd

Tags: ip, bridge, systemd

With Debian 8.1, how does one add a second IP address to a bridge interface under systems?  Like in "IP Aliasing"?

I tried it this way...

In `/etc/systemd/network` subdirectory:

File `40-br0.netdev` has:

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

File `41-br0:0.netdev` has:

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0:0
Kind=bridge
```

File `80-homelan.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
Address=172.28.1.1/22
DNS=172.28.1.1
DHCPServer=0
```

File `81-cable.network:`

```
[Match]
Name=br0:0

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.1/24
DNS=192.168.1.1
DHCPServer=0
```

The `br0:0` does not get created using above scenario.

Comment: Did you even try your own solution?

Comment: I've added more details of various `systemd` configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your `80-homelan.network` file to add a second line containing an address :

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
Address=172.28.1.1/22
Address=<second ip address>
DNS=172.28.1.1
DHCPServer=0
```

Comment: Wow.  That simple, uh?  Will wait until after work to try it out.

Comment: So have you tried it ? 

I should warn you that this does not create a br0:0 as you may expect, but you'll have two working ip addresses on br0